# OmniAuth before_filter for requiring login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

is it possible using OmniAuth to require login before certain actions?

I remember from a railscast that Devise has a before_filter, but does OmniAuth?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a `before_filter` :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :authenticate

  def authenticate
    redirect_to :login unless User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"])
  end
...
end
```

Presuming:
1. You have defined a login page with link(s) like : `<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook" %>`

See also [RailsCasts tagged with authentication](http://railscasts.com/tags/25)