# Authenticated routes with Omniauth Google

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I'm trying to make an authenticated route `/me` using [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2). So far, I have the library set up to login and logout and it's working fine. However, I want to have certain routes be accessible only when a user is logged in. I found [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477745/omniauth-before-filter-for-requiring-login) and made some small changes to fit my set up.

*application_controller.rb*

```
before_filter :authenticate
def authenticate
    redirect_to :login unless User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
end
```

*user.rb*

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
        user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.picture = auth.info.image
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.save!
    end
```

I used `env["omniauth"]` because that's the auth hash I used in my `SessionsController`.

However, now whenever I go to `localhost:3000`, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `provider' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm assuming this happens because `env["omniauth.auth"]` is not accessible from `application_controller.rb`? If that's the case, then how do I properly access the auth hash?

Comment: What does your `from_omniauth` class method look like inside your `user.rb` file?

Comment: @JustinLicata just updated the original post

Comment: `env["omniauth.auth"]` is returning `nil` when you visit "localhost:3000". The reason i believe is that this env variable gets set only in the callback request after social login. For all other requests, this will be `nil`.

Comment: Instead of doing `redirect_to :login unless User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])`, you should do something like `redirect_to :login unless user_signed_in?`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh yes, this is my thought as well - any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh thanks, how would I define the `user_signed_in?` method with omniauth?

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know if it s unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

*application_controller.rb*

```
before_filter :authenticate

def authenticate
  redirect_to :login unless user_signed_in?
end

def user_signed_in?
  !!current_user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= begin
    User.find(session[:current_user_id]) || fetch_user_from_omniauth
  end
end

def fetch_user_from_omniauth
  user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
  session[:current_user_id] = user.id
  user
end
```

This will first try to fetch the user already logged in (from session). If not found, it will try to create a user from omniauth and then set its id in session, so that for next requests, it does not need omniauth in env to find current user.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to understand your answer. Why are you skipping authenticate in `social_controller.rb`, and also what is the role of this controller? Is this the same as the one that creates the sessions?

Comment: By the way, my Sessions.rb is where the auth callback is

Comment: I modified it, please check now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, `current_user_id` is undefined, do I set it in my auth callback?

Comment: I just updated it. Please see if it still is undefined.

Comment: `Couldn't find User with 'id'=` because I believe `:current_user_id` is not defined in my application. However, in my callback controller, I do set `session[:user_id]  = user.id` so I tried replacing `:current_user_id` with `:user_id` but still receive the aforementioned error

Comment: `User.where(id: session[:user_id]).first`

Comment: If you are using `session[:user_id]`, then use it consistently everywhere. Replace `session[:current_user_id]` with `session[:user_id]` everywhere.

Comment: Yes, I did that and I still get the error described above

Comment: Did you replace `User.find` with `User.where(...).first`?

Comment: Yes, it's not making a difference

Comment: I was just able to implement `user_signed_in?` and it works fine, the other code was not necessary in my case - thank you for your help!